# Nikkor 28-70mm F2.8 lens problem: AF and aperture don't work

Tags: lens, nikon, repair, nikon-d7100

I bought this lens second hand from someone who has no idea about this kind of thing. The price WAS low, but not low enough to justify a broken lens. It has no glass scratches and at 300£ it seemed to be a steal. But, while it's crystal clear, autofocus doesn't work and neither does the auto aperture. I just don't know what to do. Is the 'consultation' at a Nikon store free? I tried it on a d7100 and on a fujifilm pro s2 I think. It should work fine. Any help is MUCH appreciated, since I'm quite desperate.

Comment: For starters you'll need to specify *which* 28-70mm f/2.8 Nikkor you have. Is it actually an AF lens? The Nikon shop should be able to tell you if the lens is basically functional, but the cost of this probably depends on how you ask.

Comment: Can you explain more about *neither does the auto aperture*? On most modern lenses the aperture itself is automatically stopped down before the shutter fires. Are you saying that this doesn't work? Or does that work, but you're having trouble with the automatic exposure system?

Comment: Also, what is the position of the `M/MA` switch on the lens?

Comment: the M/MA switch will control the AF but should have no affect on the stopping down. It sounds more like an electrical contact issue. I own a copy of that lens and about a year ago I had a similar issue. Everyone told me to trash it and by a 24-70 2.8 or expect and $800 repair.  I paid $167 for a flawless repair. TOTALLY WORTH IT. Just make sure that you take it to a place where the quotes are free.